# What are pros of PC stick?

Tags: windows-10, performance

I consider buying modecom FreePC but does it replace tower ATX? What are pros of type of this mini PC? my PC is unstable and I want to replace case with FreePC

Comment: This question is open to interpretation and opinion and is really better suited for a forum environment where open discussion can help bring out the possible answers. SuperUser is better at specific problems and specific solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It purely depends on what you do.

Main Pros on any Stick-shaped PCs:

- Tiny
- Usually fairly cheap
- Portable
- Low power consumption (may be important to some people)

Main Cons on any Stick-shaped PCs:

- General use only (fairly low-end spec)
- All parts are "as-is" and not-upgradable (except storage as you can add microSD card)
- Minimum amount of USB ports that can limit external devices connection (1 USB = 1 keyboard, or 1 mouse, and you're stuck, unless you use a USB hub, or USB Wireless Keyboard+Mouse combo)

If you only plan to browse the web, read email, and not storing much on it, it is a great thing to have and bring to places as the only requirement to use it is basically a keyboard+mouse and a monitor/tv with HDMI and USB cable (to power it up)